# HTTP CalloutException in Summer '19 sandboxes

Tags: apex, httprequest, summer19, calloutexception

Yesterday I started experiencing intermittent but frequent errors with HTTP callouts using Named Credentials in Apex in multiple sandboxes (all Summer '19 preview instances).

These same callouts had been working without issue up until yesterday.  The errors initially appeared to be precipitated by enabling "Let users access Salesforce records from Outlook" under Setup > Outlook Integration and Sync, but in subsequent tests today, I was reproducing the issue in all Summer '19 sandboxes, regardless of whether that setting had been enabled.  The issue couldn't be reproduced in any Spring '19 sandboxes (so far).  Multiple external HTTP endpoints appear to be affected.

Exception: **CalloutException**

Message: **Remote host closed connection during handshake**

Has anyone else experienced this?  Any ideas about root causes, areas to investigate, or workarounds?

Comment: We are facing the issue with Named Creds too since yesterday and I am getting a strong feeling that it is because of the TLS change that Salesforce is planning. I have not heard back anything on it from Salesforce. If you could check the following documentation which describes it in detail. May be you should also check what TLS setting does your outbound call URL is on. 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000221207&type=1

Comment: We faced the same issue yesterday. But the calls are working today.

Comment: Indeed -- it looks like we are back up and running too (for the moment, at least)